# what do GCC attributes `_dl_argv` and `_dl_argv_internal` do?

Tags: gcc

what is the purpose of `_dl_argv` and `_dl_argv_internal`?  it *looks* like they have to do with `dlopen`, but that's all i'd hazard to guess.  are they really attributes, or is my nomenclature out of whack?

i've been googling and all i can find is patches and error messages, but no explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you think this is a GCC attribute?

I found this in the GCC sources:

```
extern char **_dl_argv_internal __attribute__ ((alias ("_dl_argv")));
```

*But*, that actually occurs in a comment, the attribute in use is "alias", and I'm not even sure if that's valid because "alias" is not a documented attribute type (for variables).

Both symbols appear as variables in Glibc. As you speculate, they're to do with the dynamic linker, but *not* specifically to do with `dlopen`. In fact, these are to the dynamic linker (usually something like `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`) as `argv` is to `int main(int argc, char **argv)` in user code. Getting a dynamic linker up and running is a bit more involved than just having a function called `main`, so there's some assembler code, and some system calls involved, but that variable ends up holding the command-line parameters just the same. (In fact, it is the dynamic linker's job to call your `main` once it's done all that bring up work.)

Does that answer your question, or were you referring to something else?